# Navigation controller: in landscape mode, going "back" animation pushes down

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller. When In landscape mode, the back button animation pushes down, rather than to the right.

What do I need to do to make it push right like it does in portrait mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this happen before if one of your UIViewController's does not have landscape support.

Double check your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in both of your UIViewControllers and make sure they both return YES for both portrait and landscape.

Comment: That resolved it for me, thank you. I need to wait 3 more mins before marking an answer as correct, will do it then. :)